# Problem while attempting to change selected index of a tabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

The problem i face is quite annoying.

I have a tabControl with the 2 tabItems(Home,Show)
The Home tab starts as Visible and Show as Hidden

In Home i have an image for which i handle the MouseLeftButtonDown event.
This event should change the visibility of Show TabItem and make it Selected.

At the code i have a tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
which forces the tabControl SelectionChangeEvent (which i use to change the foreground
of the Show and Home TabItems).

The problem i face is that instead of the focus to get passed to Show, it remains on Home.
I have no problem with the code, because at the last step of the SelectionChange event handler ,which is the last function that gets executed by my code, what i see in the ui is correct.

So what gets executed after that?
Can anybody help?

```
private void Main_clientImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)  
{  
         showMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  
         setTabSelected("showMenu");  
}   



public void setTabSelected(String name)  
{  
   for (int i = 0; i  tabControl.Items.Count ; i++)  
   {  
         TabItem item = tabControl.Items.GetItemAt(i) as TabItem;  
         if (item.Name.Equals(name))  
         {  
             selectedTab=i;  
             tabControl.SelectedIndex = i;  
             item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);  
         }  
         else  
         {  
             item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);  
         }  
     }  
}  

private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      for (int i = 0; i  tabControl.Items.Count; i++)
      {
          TabItem item = tabControl.Items.GetItemAt(i) as TabItem;
           if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == i)
           {
               item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
           }
           else
           {
               item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
           }
       }
}
```

//EDIT: I solved it by adding a simple e.Handler = true at MouseLeftButtonDown event.
Whats wrong with this thing???

Comment: Are you setting your Visibility before you change the SelectedIndex? My best guess is the Visibility is set to Hidden when the SelectedIndex gets changed, and you cannot set focus to a non-visible item.

Comment: Can you post some code? We don't know what "(which i use to change the foreground of the Show and Home TabItems)." is. Are you setting the visibility of the tab you are trying to set as the selected tab?

Comment: I posted the code on my post.Thnx for the help.As you can see i set the Visibility of the tab before the change of selectedIndex.

Comment: This sounds like a really strange UI.

Comment: @Fotis,  Adding e.Handler=true, will not propogate the MouseLeftButtonDown event further to the visual elements present inside the TabControl.  I think this event is not really required.  Please post the XAML part as well.

Comment: Answers do not belong into the question, remove your edit from there and post it as an answer please (also accept it as soon as you are allowed to, to conclude this question)

Comment: @ H.B. how to do this?
@ Prince Coder: The .xaml is about 1000lines  do you mind telling which part? The tabControl? the items?

Answer (score 3):

I changed the `SelectedItem` of `TabControl` in a method
`void open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`
and did it from a `<Button Click="open_Click"` and from a `<DataGrid MouseDoubleClick="open_Click"`.

Only by adding

```
e.Handled = true;
```

at the end of in method `open_Click` it worked for the `MouseDoubleClick` as Fotis mentioned in the question.

Comment: like 7 years later I had a similar problem, I fixed it using b.handled=true.   why does that work?

Comment: It's completely ridiculous, but "handled=true" helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your code.

```
private void Main_clientImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)  
{  
    showMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  
    homeMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    setTabSelected("showMenu");  
}   

public void setTabSelected(String name)  
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.Items.Count; i++)  
    {  
        TabItem item = tabControl.Items.GetItemAt(i) as TabItem;  
        if (item.Header.Equals(name))  
        {  
            selectedTab = i;  
            item.IsSelected = true; 
            item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);  
        }
        else  
        {  
            item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);  
        }  
    }  
}  

private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        TabItem item = tabControl.Items.GetItemAt(i) as TabItem;
        if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == i)
        {
            item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }
        else
        {
            item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I am checking `item.Header.Equals(name)` and set `item.IsSelected = true`. Sometimes selectionindex doesn't work properly. The above code should address your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the SelectedItem property of the TabControl has changed, you need to make sure that SelectedItem.IsFocused = true. If not just use SelectedItem.Focus() right after you changed the SelectedItem property. It helped in my case.

Comment: "Focus()" call doesn't help.